# mvc 3 assign class for all textboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

how do I assign class for all textboxes created using textboxfor?

Is there a way using a template override?

I know there are template overrides by type, but I don't want to target a particular type.  I want to add a rounded-corner css class to all textboxes.

Comment: Just make a CSS rule. Dirt simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why MVC need to be in charge of *rounding* the text boxes.  It would be much easier just to use CSS with a `.input[type=textbox]`.

Comment: what if I had to apply many styles already grouped into classes via a 3rd party like jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
input[type="textbox"]{border-radius: 0.5em;}
```

Comment: this would work for this particular case, but there should still be a way of adding specific css classes to a set of controls rendered via html helpers

Comment: That would be using `EditorFor` and specifying a template.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a css rule(s) would be the best option for this, but if you need to add a class, this may be easier to achieve with a startup script and jQuery than on the server side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input[type=text]").addClass("foo");
});
```

Comment: I don't want to do this via js, since there's a delay for the js to load and there will be a flicker